# "IOR must have at least one IIOP profile" error while deploying application to Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

I'm developing an application which receives messages using message driven bean and persist data into the database. While trying to deploy it on glassfish, I receive following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: IIOP Protocol Manager initialization failed.  Possible cause is that ORB is not available in this container
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeProtocolManager(BaseContainer.java:827)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.<init>(BaseContainer.java:508)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.<init>(MessageBeanContainer.java:142)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:121)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:230)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:108)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:264)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr
        at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getProtocolManager(GlassFishORBHelper.java:219)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeProtocolManager(BaseContainer.java:824)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.omg.CORBA.BAD_OPERATION: FINE: IOP01210086: Could not bind initial GIS to name service  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 86  completed: No
        at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.initORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:622)
        at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.getORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:263)
        at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.createORB(GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.java:93)
        at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:152)
        ... 62 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.BAD_OPERATION: FINE: IOP01210086: Could not bind initial GIS to name service  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 86  completed: No
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
        at $Proxy216.bindNameException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.folb.InitialGroupInfoService.bindName(InitialGroupInfoService.java:215)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.folb.InitialGroupInfoService.<init>(InitialGroupInfoService.java:177)
        at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.initORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:611)
        ... 65 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.INV_OBJREF: WARNING: IOP00511001: IOR must have at least one IIOP profile  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1001  completed: No
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
        at $Proxy227.iorMustHaveIiopProfile(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.ior.IORImpl.getProfile(IORImpl.java:366)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.CorbaContactInfoListImpl.setLocalSubcontract(CorbaContactInfoListImpl.java:444)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.CorbaContactInfoListImpl.setEffectiveTargetIOR(CorbaContactInfoListImpl.java:277)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.CorbaContactInfoListImpl.setTargetIOR(CorbaContactInfoListImpl.java:219)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.CorbaContactInfoListImpl.<init>(CorbaContactInfoListImpl.java:183)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.transport.TransportDefault$1.create(TransportDefault.java:70)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.ORBUtility.makeClientDelegate(ORBUtility.java:803)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.ORBUtility.makeObjectReference(ORBUtility.java:812)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.ior.ObjectReferenceProducerBase.make_object(ObjectReferenceProducerBase.java:78)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.oa.ObjectAdapterBase.makeObject(ObjectAdapterBase.java:126)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.oa.poa.POAImpl.create_reference_with_id(POAImpl.java:1559)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.folb.InitialGroupInfoService.bindName(InitialGroupInfoService.java:203)
        ... 67 more
```

I look around and realise that it may be a CORBA problem, but I'm not using CORBA, the message is sent via ActiveMQ and I use ojdbc for database.

Sorry for the long log and short description. If you need more information, please let me know. Anyway, all answers and suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, "IIOP Protocol Manager initialization failed. Possible cause is that ORB is not available in this container" when trying to deploy an app in glassfish 4.
In my case, the reason is that I changed the thread pool on one of my http-listeners . I wanted to use the "thread-pool" instead of the "http-thread-pool" (because It had more threads). As soon as I changed back, it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem now. After sometime trying to understand the problem and several restarts of glassfish, I rebooted the server and the problem is now gone.

Comment: seems to me like that's a common pattern with JEE application servers and IDEs in use when developing for them.